# CsvHelper library not able to parse datetime

Tags: c#, csv, datetime, csvhelper

I am using the CsvHelper library to parse CSV files into an object list.

I have added the datetime format to the class as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss t` but I'm getting an error while parsing. The date is in the following format:

```
public class Claim
{
    [Name("Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Name("Number")]
    public string Number{ get; set; }
    [Name("Date")]
    [Format("dd/MM/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")]
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}
```

Below I am using the CsvHelper library to parse the CSV file

```
 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var claims = csvReader.GetRecords<Claim>().ToList();
                return claims;
            }
        }
```

the following is

```
2022-04-19 12:00:00 AM
```

sample CSV:

```
Name,Number,Date
XTC,2545454545,2022-04-19 0:00
JCF,7878421215,2022-01-20 0:00
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> Unhandled exception. `CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException`: The conversion cannot be performed.
> Text: '2022-04-19 12:00:00 AM'
> MemberName: Date
> MemberType: `System.DateTime`
> TypeConverter: '`CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DateTimeConverter`'

I tried the following solutions:

```
 var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" } };
 csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
```

and:

```
csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>()

public sealed class CsvMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<Claim>
    {
        public CsvMap()
        {
            const string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            var culture= CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    
            Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption.Format(format)
                .TypeConverterOption.CultureInfo(culture);
        }
    }
```

but I'm still getting the above exception.

How can I fix this so that I can parse the given datetime?

Comment: "10-08-2022" does not look like "2022-08-10" and does not match the yyyy-MM-dd format.

Comment: "2022-01-20 0:00" doesn't match either of the formats you've specified.

Comment: (It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] so we don't need to guess at anything.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the wrong date format string:

```
2022-04-19 0:00
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm
```

or

```
2022-04-19 12:00:00 AM
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt
```

The example you have provided and the error message do not match, so in this example I have provided mapping for both!

- `h` will only work for 12 hour values, so less than or equal to 12, so it will overflow for values like 14. If there is no provision for the am/pm designator (`tt`) *ALL* hour values be interpreted as `am`, so only use `h` in conjunction with `tt`.
- `H` (single `H`) is necessary to parse single digit hour values, but it will also match on double digit hours and correctly interpret them as 24 hour times.

Only use double hour characters (`hh`/`HH`) in scenarios where you want to *force* a leading zero output or when you *know* that the input will *always* have a leading zero. *For parsing inputs we will always use the single hour indicator* because it will work for single hour, leading zero and double digit hour inputs.

You just need to change the format expression in the `FormatAttribute`:

Read more about C# [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

```
[Format("dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm", "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt")] 
public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
```

You can see a proof of this here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/orIGv9